# Excel SUM based on dynamic range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, sumifs

I have below data in excel.

| Product | Room | 09/13/2021 | 09/12/2021 | 09/11/2021 | 08/10/2021 | 08/09/2021 | 08/08/2021 | 08/07/2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | White | 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| A | Black | 2 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| B | White | 3 | 9 | 1 | 1 | 6 | 9 | 1 |
| B | Black | 4 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| C | White | 5 | 4 | 7 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 7 |
| C | Black | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 1 | 4 |

---

I want to see if there is a good way to replace Formula with excel formulas.
[image]

Where:

**Formula 1** = Sum of last three days (first three columns so columns C, D, E) for Product= A and Room = White. Which is sum of cell C2+D2+E2 = 1+1+2 = 4

**Formula 2** = Sum of values where Month of Date is 8 in row 1 and for Product = A and Room = White. Which is sum of cell F2+G2+H2+I2 = 4+2+1+1 = 8

I tried using =SUMPRODUCT() with VLOOKUP =SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(C6,B12:F18,{3,4,5},0)) from this [link](https://www.excel-university.com/return-the-sum-of-two-or-more-columns-with-vlookup/) but how can I dynamically pick the array of columns.

Comment: You are asking for 5 formula, without showing what you have attempted to do on your own.  A little broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get your first request.  Use Evaluate Formulas to understand how it works, see if you can apply it to your other needs.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:I7)*(A2:A7="A")*(B2:B7="White")*(C1:I1>TODAY()-3))
```